# Document ready button.click only works in console

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button`<button id="stbutton"></button>` and I can enter into the Chrome Dev Console `$('#stbutton').click();` and it works. Sounds easy enough, however:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#stbutton").click();
});
```

Doesn't work. Also tried waiting for the parent div to load, no dice,

```
 $('#panel').ready(function () {
    $("#stbutton").click();
});
```

As for this page, I know it works in console. And jquery is definitely being loaded before it hits this line of code.

Comment: Probably calling that before any click event handler is bound to element, or before element exists. No way to know from what little is shown. Where is the event handler code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @charlietfl pointed out, you're probably triggering the event before attaching the click listener to the element.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   $("#stbutton").click(); //This doesn't work
  
  
   $("#stbutton").on("click", function(){
      alert("clicked");
   }); 
  
   $("#stbutton").click(); //trigger event after listening to it.

});
```

```css
#stbutton {
  background: #000;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
<div id="stbutton"></div>
```

Comment: I tried that one as well, no dice. I think I need something after document.ready, something I can target that's not part of the DOM even

Comment: Please post a little bit more of code, the button event handler if you're setting it, so we can help you. Try to setup a fiddle where you can replicate the error.

Comment: I found $(window).load in another post, once I thought about 'after' document ready I found it. That works for some reason. Here's the code btw http://codepen.io/teachtyler/pen/wMYddw. I forgot I had a codepen example.

Comment: I know you may want to "protect" your code, but I won't go through a minified "beautified" javascript code. You shouldn't need window load for this things, you probably have something wrong going on, but if it worked for you, cheers ;)

Comment: Haha, that's what I'm saying I spent waayy too long trying to get document.ready to work in some way, but it's getting late so I'm content with this.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('#stbutton').click();
})
```

I found the magic that is window.load!

Comment: .load() was deprecated as of jQuery 1.8, and removed as of 3.0... Use .on( "load", handler ) instead.